# Use object as key in a Tcl array

Tags: arrays, oop, hashmap, tcl

As I understand it, everything can be used as a key in Tcl arrays.
For example, this class:

```
class create MyClass {
  variable name
  constructor {newName} {
    set name $newName
  }
  method clone {} {
    return [MyClass new $name]
  }
}
```

I can use an instance of this class to reference data in an array like this:

```
set key [MyClass new test]
array set test_array [list $key "data"]
puts $test_array($key)
->data
```

However, if I use another instance of the same object, the data is not retrieved. For example:

```
set new_key [$key clone]
puts $test_array($new_key)
->no such element in array
```

I understand that as in TCL everything is considered as a string so as the references are differents, it cannot match.

Nevertheless I would like to know if there is some way to make arrays look to the content of the key like in Java for example where `equals` and `hashcode` methods should be overridden to obtain the wanted behavior.

Comment: The value you are setting the key to isn't the name, but the unique object identifier. I'll see if I can cook up something when I get home, unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. That is why I am looking for a solution which will call a method instead of the reference. I am looking forward to your proposal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get what you're after, but at least one part of it seems to be to be able to choose different ways to get key values from objects when indexing an associative structure. In languages that are object-oriented from the ground up, this is fairly straightforward as you only need to override how the associative structure gets keys from index objects, or to override how the index objects produce keys.

In Tcl, neither the `array` nor the `dict` structure is object-oriented out of the box. There are ways to use traces to override how members of an `array` are indexed, but it can get ugly and brittle, unless someone as skilled as I tries it. So, after trying to make that work for some time, I made an OO wrapper for a `dict` instead.

Here's the class that describes index-producing objects, as per your description.

```
oo::class create MyClass {
    variable name
    constructor args {
        lassign $args name
    }
    method data {} {
        set name
    }
}
```

The wrapper just keeps a `dict` called `data`, and also remembers the name of a method to get a key value from an object: by default `data`. The `dict` can be populated through the constructor, or left empty initially.

```
oo::class create MyArray {
    variable data method
    constructor args {
        set data $args
        set method data
    }
    method setKeyMethod m {
        set method $m
    }
    method get key {
        dict get $data [$key $method]
    }
    method set {key value} {
        dict set data [$key $method] $value
    }
}
```

Behavior: `setKeyMethod` changes the name of the key-producing method. `set` sets a member in the dictionary, given an index-capable object and a value. `get` gets a member in the dictionary, given an index-capable object.

```
% MyArray create test_array
::test_array
% set key [MyClass new test]
::oo::Obj64
% test_array set $key foo
test foo
% set key2 [::oo::copy $key]
::oo::Obj65
% test_array get $key2
foo
```

I.e. different objects that produce the same key value get the same value from the dictionary object.

This structure does *not* store references to the index-producing objects, but it's easy enough to make it do that. Since I can't figure out why, I don't really see a good way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful. Is there a reason about using `dict` over `array` ?

Comment: @Krouitch: no strong reason: it's just a slightly better semantic fit. Depending on what one wants to do with the MyArray structure, either one could prove superior.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are not serializable without some work.  The object reference, when converted to a string returns the object identifier (e.g. ::oo::Obj145), not the contents of the object.

If I am reading your question correctly you want a key based on the content of your object.   You will need to write a method to convert your object's data into a string that you wish to use as a key.

```
::oo::class create MyClass {
  variable name
  constructor {newName} {
    set name $newName
  }
  method toString {} {
    my variable name
    return $name
  }
  method clone {} {
    return [MyClass new $name]
  }
}

set obj [MyClass new test]
set key [$obj toString]
array set test_array [list $key "data"]
puts "$key: $test_array($key)"
#->test: data

set new_obj [$obj clone]
set new_key [$new_obj toString]
puts "$new_key: $test_array($new_key)"
#->test: data
```

Also there is a `::oo::copy` function available for cloning purposes.

Comment: I thought about this solution however, I am looking for a solution which keeps the reference to the object in the key too.
I am not sure at all that it is possible in Tcl however...

Thanks for the `::oo::copy`